# mod_rewrite - redirect from one domain to another and preserve trailing values in url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I think this is a pretty straight forward question in mod_rewrite:

I got one domain, which needs to redirect to another, but keep any value after last slash (/) in the first URL, over to the second.

domain.com/4433 should transfer to domain.com/folder/?p=4333

Listed for clarity:

**From: domain.com/4433**

**To: domain.com/folder/?p=4333**

Any ideas?

Edit: 
Did some testing, we found the following solution:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
>
> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]*)$ /folder/?p=$1 [NC]

sincerely,
- bakkelun

Comment: Do you want to have an HTTP-redirect or have the server do this in the background without the user noticing?

Comment: it should be done without the user noticing. But we've found the solution, it was: 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]*)$ /folder/?p=$1 [NC]

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/folder?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If both domains run with the same vhost, then this will give an endless redirect loop.

Comment: @Residuum: Not just in that case. The *Substitution* is just a relative path. So `/4433` would be redirected to `/domain.com/folder?p=4433` that would be redirected to `/domain.com/domain.com/folder?p=domain.com/folder` that would be redirected to `/domain.com/domain.com/domain.com/folder?p=domain.com/domain.com/folder` etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting on my careless answer. I tried to put in a (perhaps another careless) fix. I guess the real solution would then depend on how the complete set of valid urls look for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: domain.com = domain1.com and domain2.com? domain1.com should be redirected to domain2.com? Both run on the same server (optional)?

**[EDIT:]**

If you really only want to do the thing as stated in the comment, then do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^4433$ http://domain2.com/folder/?p=4433 [R=301,L]
```

Else, as Benedikt Eger said, or with R=301 if you want real redirection.
Or, if you want it to redirect only on numbers, then do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])+$ http://domain2.com/folder/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

RewriteCond checks, if defined vhost is domain1.com, but not domain2.com, then the rewrite rule is applied, and redirects via HTTP status 301 [R=301] only number strings (0-9)+ consisting of at least one number to the specified URL. [L] makes this the last rule applied.

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to mention it, but ONLY accesses to domain/4433 should redirect to domain.com/folder/?p=4333

"domain.com" alone should not redirect.

Comment: You mixed something up. `[(0-9)+]` should rather be `([0-9])+`.

Comment: Thanks, Gumbo. I have fixed that typo / thinko.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't really want to redirect but to have pretty URLs, you can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /folder?p=$1 [L]
```

This takes everything after the first slash and inserts it at the $1 - but only if there's something after the slash. It doesn't issue a redirect so the users won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /folder/?p=$1
```

If you want to use the rule in a .htaccess file, remove the leading slashes.